# Calva fails to lanch betterthantomorrow.calva-2.0.214\clojure-lsp.exe_backup.exe

Tags: vscode-calva

Since today Calva fails with

```
[Error - 12:47:40] Starting client failed
Launching server using command c:\Users\ros1sgm\.vscode\extensions\betterthantomorrow.calva-2.0.214\clojure-lsp.exe_backup.exe failed.
```

I have updated to Visual Studio Code September 2021 (version 1.61):

```
Version: 1.61.0 (user setup)
Commit: ee8c7def80afc00dd6e593ef12f37756d8f504ea
Date: 2021-10-07T18:13:09.652Z
Electron: 13.5.1
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763
```

Has anybody an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After I removed vspacecode related plugins, the warning went away, maybe you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

https://calva.io/clojure-lsp/

I also meet this problem, it's confusing.

You can click clojure-lsp at the left bottom of vscode, and then click download clojure-lsp. Just like the official document of Calva.